# Bash shell scripting , how to use pipes in command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

Trying to use pipes in bash script. This works fine on my Linux shell but bash script errors out. What am I doing wrong?

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #some code
  cmd="cat file2 | grep ':'  | awk -F \":\" '{print \$1}' > pool_names"
  echo $cmd
  exec $cmd
```

I see this error

```
cat: invalid option -- 'F'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that — you'd need to use `eval "$cmd"` to get the pipes evaluated as pipes rather than strings, but using `eval` is downright dangerous.  You could also use `bash -c "$cmd"` but that's equivalent to `eval`.  I reserve the right to be wrong in using quotes in `eval "$cmd"` (maybe it should be `eval $cmd`), but it still isn't safe to use `eval`.

Comment: To clarify, you are calling `cat` with the arguments `file2`, `|`, `grep`, `:`, `|`, `awk`, `-F`, etc.  `cat` is treating the first 6 arguments as filenames (or, it would if it got that far), but doesn't recognize `-F` as a valid option so it is aborting.

Comment: You're in luck though; `cat | grep | awk` is an anti-pattern and you can easily avoid the pipes completely.

Comment: Be sure to read ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, a "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator. (See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), while a pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by the control operator '|'  (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02).  When the shell sees the line `exec $cmd` it does not see the control operator `|`, so that is a simple command.  (This has nothing to do with `exec`, and the same behavior will occur with any command.)  It then expands the variables in the line and follows the rule `the first field shall be considered the command name and remaining fields are the arguments for the command`, so `exec` is called with a bunch of arguments.  `exec` does not attempt to interpret the arguments as shell operators (perhaps you meant to use `eval` instead of `exec`), but just passes all the arguments on to `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

The **bash** builtin `exec` command has a completely different goal, as explained at https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/exec.htm .

You have to substitute `exec` with `eval` in order to get your script working, or as alternative, as suggested by @Jonathan Leffler in a comment, you may use `bash -c "$cmd"`.